# Dual Monitor Setup with KVM Switch: Random Screen Blankouts in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have a dual monitor setup connected to a KVM switch (link: https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005005992520783.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.147.21ef194de9qFxg&gatewayAdapt=glo2esp), with one monitor connected via HDMI and the other via DPI. I'm running Kubuntu 23.10 with the default screen display settings. The laptop screen (a Thinkpad) is disabled as part of the configuration.

The issue I'm facing is that randomly, one or both of the screens go blank. Sometimes it's one screen, sometimes the other, and occasionally both. Rebooting the system usually resolves the issue temporarily.

I've tried using alternatives such as arandr to configure the display settings, but the problem persists.  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or resolve it.

Running `lspci ; xrandr` returns the following and, during a few seconds, turns black the secondary screen:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-V (rev 21)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 600P Series (rev 03)



Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080     60.02 +  60.02    48.01  
   1680x1050     60.02  
   1400x1050     60.02  
   1600x900      60.02  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1400x900      60.02  
   1280x960      60.02  
   1440x810      60.02  
   1368x768      60.02  
   1280x800      60.02  
   1280x720      60.02  
   1024x768      60.02  
   960x720       60.02  
   928x696       60.02  
   896x672       60.02  
   1024x576      60.02  
   960x600       60.02  
   960x540       60.02  
   800x600       60.02  
   840x525       60.02  
   864x486       60.02  
   700x525       60.02  
   800x450       60.02  
   640x512       60.02  
   700x450       60.02  
   640x480       60.02  
   720x405       60.02  
   684x384       60.02  
   640x360       60.02  
   512x384       60.02  
   512x288       60.02  
   480x270       60.02  
   400x300       60.02  
   432x243       60.02  
   320x240       60.02  
   360x202       60.02  
   320x180       60.02  
HDMI-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Has anyone experienced similar issues with a dual monitor setup and KVM switch in Kubuntu? Are there any specific troubleshooting steps or alternative configurations I could try to resolve this issue? Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] with `lspci ; xrandr`

Comment: Thanks @DanielT! I just did. Interestingly, when I run the command, one of the screens goes black for a few seconds... but I don't know how that might be related to the problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please [edit] with the `lspci` part that's missing

Comment: Done, thanks! :)

Comment: So you are using an Intel integrated GPU. It might not be able to drive that many displays. Try lowering the resolution and seeing whether the system becomes more stable

Comment: Oh, thanks! I will give it a try. Interestingly, when running a similar configuration in Windows 10 on the same laptop it does not offer those problems. But I will give it a try with lower resolutions. Cheers!

Comment: Running `xrand` with a lower resolution, also makes one of the screen to go black. Would that also be related to using an Intel integrated GPU? Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen xrandr causing a black screen. It might be reading or writing to ask for extra data from the monitor. I think the GPU is struggling to sync its clocks with the monitors, and the extra data and the KVM switch may be making that worse. Also try with different cables, because a broken cable will also cause sync problems

Comment: Thanks @DanielT! Following your advice (and a similar isue with xrand which I have just found - https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=192084), I have just tried replacing it with a new cable. I tried both options: monitor to KVM and laptop to KVM... with the same results (since I am able to reproduce now the error with xrandr, is what I am using for the testing). No luck :(